# trying to get Bootstrap 3 carousel to fit to full screen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullscreen, carousel

When I run this the image and carousel overflow and you have to scroll down on the page to see the bottom of image and carousel...

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->

<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
<img src= "/assets/run3.jpg" width = "100%" alt="photo">
<div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>Sign Up Now!</h3>
<p>This is Where amazing happens</p>
    </div>
  </div>


<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

here is what happens: dropbox.com/sh/tdo3928f453123h/jTbquZNM37

Comment: Can you give your site link or show us an example on JS FIDDLE?

Comment: no site, running app off computer. Ive never used jsfiddle before

Comment: ok. So, can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I dont have enough rep to post a screenshot

Comment: Hey! You can upload your screenshot somewhere like Dropbox and give me a link for the same. Upload it on some photo sharing site and just paste the link here.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Comment: What's the image size? Full screen example: http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/slider

Comment: varying image sizes but want all to fit full screen

Comment: here is what happens: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tdo3928f453123h/jTbquZNM37

Comment: the first picture shows how the page loads and it is cut off, the second picture is if you scroll down on the page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force your slider & image width and height :

```
#carousel-example-generic,
#carousel-example-generic .item,
#carousel-example-generic .item img {
  height: 100%;
}
#carousel-example-generic .item img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/104726#)

Note : this won't keep proportions, but it could fit your needs.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I am adding this CSS code to my bootswatch.css.less file, is there a particular way I need to add it?